# Python - Optimal way to re-assign global variables from function in other module

Tags: python, import, module, global-variables

I have a module which I called entities.py - there are 2 classes within it and 2 global variables as in below pattern:

```
FIRST_VAR = ...
SECOND_VAR = ...

class FirstClass:
    [...]

class SecondClass:
    [...]
```

I also have another module (let's call it main.py for now) where I import both classes and constants as like here:

```
from entities import FirstClass, SecondClass, FIRST_VAR, SECOND_VAR
```

In the same "main.py" module I have another constant: `THIRD_VAR = ...`, and another class, in which all of imported names are being used.

Now, I have a function, which is being called only if a certain condition is met (passing config file path as CLI argument in my case). As my best bet, I've written it as following:

```
def update_consts_from_config(config: ConfigParser):
    global FIRST_VAR
    global SECOND_VAR
    global THIRD_VAR
    FIRST_VAR = ...
    SECOND_VAR = ...
    THIRD_VAR = ...
```

This works perfectly fine, although PyCharm indicates two issues, which at least I don't consider accurate.

`from entities import FirstClass, SecondClass, FIRST_VAR, SECOND_VAR` - here it warns me that FIRST_VAR and SECOND_VAR are unused imports, but from my understanding and testing they are used and not re-declared elsewhere unless function `update_consts_from_config` is invoked.

Also, under `update_consts_from_config` function:

`global FIRST_VAR` - at this and next line, it says
*Global variable FIRST_VAR is undefined at the module level*

My question is, should I really care about those warnings and (as I think the code is correct and clear), or am I missing something important and should come up with something different here?

I know I can do something as:

```
import entities
from entities import FirstClass, SecondClass

FIRST_VAR = entities.FIRST_VAR
SECOND_VAR = entities.SECOND_VAR
```

and work from there, but this look like an overkill for me, `entities` module has only what I have to import in `main.py` which also strictly depends on it, therefore I would rather stick to importing those names explicitly than referencing them by `entities.` just for that reason

What do you think would be a best practice here? I would like my code to clear, unambiguous and somehow optimal.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use global variables.

Comment: It seems for me that `global FIRST_VAR` is creating a new variable instead of altering a variable from the imported document. Have you tried print `FIRST_VAR` in order to check it? Maybe you should think in either make this variables static class variables or use `entities.FIRST_VAR` as you mentioned. I'm not sure if python can invoke a variable from other module as a global variable.

Comment: If you insist on using global variables then you should use ‘entities.FIRST_VAR’ everywhere in main.py

Comment: @quamrana Thank you for the comment. I am aware of it, I'm not using global variables on regular basis, it just made sense for me to declare those in this very situation as global variables in the same fashion as `pi` is declared as global variable in Math module.

Comment: @FlavioMoraes Yes I've tried that, during debugging FIRST_VAR appeared as when it was declared in both function and main frame, and after executing re-assignment it changed in both function frame and main frame as I would have expected.
"I'm not sure if python can invoke a variable from other module as a global variable" - That's the tricky part I'm also not quite sure about. Anyways thank you, I may use entities.FIRST_VAR if that makes more sense

Comment: Except it seems to me very *unlike* math.pi. You seem to be updating your variables. Firstly try not to use global variables, secondly I’m not sure assigning to them will do what you think it will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import only entities, then refer to variables in its [namespace](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/) to access/modify them.

Note:  this pattern, modifying constants in other modules (which then, to purists, aren't so much constants as globals) can be justified.  I have tons of cases where I use constants, rather than [magic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), as module level configuration.  However, for example for testing, I might reach in and modify these constants.  Say to switch a cache expiry from 2 days to 0.1 seconds to test caching.  Or like you propose, to override configuration.  Tread carefully, but it can be useful.

**main.py**:

```
import entities

def update_consts_from_config(FIRST_VAR):
    entities.FIRST_VAR = FIRST_VAR

firstclass = entities.FirstClass()

print(f"{entities.FIRST_VAR=} before override")
firstclass.debug()
entities.debug()

update_consts_from_config("override")

print(f"{entities.FIRST_VAR=} after override")
firstclass.debug()
entities.debug()
```

**entities.py**:

```
FIRST_VAR = "ori"

class FirstClass:
    def debug(self):
        print(f"entities.py:{FIRST_VAR=}")


def debug():
    print(f"making sure no closure/locality effects after object instantation {FIRST_VAR=}")
```

**$ python main.py**

```
entities.FIRST_VAR='ori' before override
entities.py:FIRST_VAR='ori'
making sure no closure/locality effects after object instantation FIRST_VAR='ori'
entities.FIRST_VAR='override' after override
entities.py:FIRST_VAR='override'
making sure no closure/locality effects after object instantation FIRST_VAR='override'
```

Now, if FIRST_VAR wasn't a string, int or another type of immutable, you should I think be able to import it separately and *mutate* it.  Like `SECOND_VAR.append("config override")` in main.py.  But *assigning* to a global in main.py will only affect affect the main.py *binding*, so if you want to share actual state between main.py and entities and other modules, everyone, not just main.py needs to `import entities` then access `entities.FIRST_VAR`.

Oh, and if you had:

```
class SecondClass:

   def __init__(self):
      self.FIRST_VAR = FIRST_VAR
```

then its instance-level value of that immutable string/int would **not** be affected by any overrides done **after** an instance creation.  Mutables like lists or dictionaries **would** be affected because they're all different bindings pointing to the same variable.

Last, wrt to those "tricky" namespaces.  `global` in your original code means: "dont consider FIRST_VAR as a variable to assign in `update_consts_from_config` s local namespace , instead assign it to **main.py** global, script-level namespace".

It does **not** mean "assign it to some global state magically shared between **entities.py** and **main.py**".  `__builtins__` *might* be that beast but modifying it is considered extremely bad form in Python.

Comment: Thank you JL for the explanation.
At last, I modified the code so that it uses static class attributes rather than global variables.
I knew I was working on a script-level namespace, but thanks to your answer I realized that assignment I wrote might have been ambiguous if other people used the code. If I were to modify the constant, I should do it truly globally, whereas assigning value to new variable and than changing it within the script should be enough for the script-local purpose.

Comment: "global" variables, whether they are at module level, static class vars or even singletons, which some people, not unreasonably, push back against as glorified globals are one thing.  Thing is, for configuration, well, you kinda have to end up with info at one spot.  However, specifically the `global` keyword in functions, rather than the general fuzzy concept of globals, has, at least in *my* code, always turned out to be somewhat of a code smell.